# Relative and absolute links in Magento

Tags: footer, link

Ok so i have about 15 footer links of pages at my homepage.I have all the pages designed and i have set them all in footer static block.But i can access them only from my homepage if i access them from any category page or checkout page it gives an 404 error page not found.
Details:
For example here is my page FAQ:
The URL Key of FAQ page is:

```
apollo-faqs
```

whereas in footer static block the link of FAQ is as under:

```
<li> <a href="apollo-faqs">FAQ's</a> </li>
```

My site's url is: 
[My Site](http://www.apollo-sports.com.pk/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to put the links like this:

```
<a href="{{store _direct="diapollo-faqs"}}">FAQ's</a>
```

Comment: It works wonders.Thanks mate thanks a million.

Answer (score -4):

Looks like you just need a forward slash / in front of your link, so it would be...

```
<li> <a href="/apollo-faqs">FAQ's</a> </li>
```

Comment: this won't work if you use the store codes in url or if you have magento installed in a subfolder.

Comment: @user3346078 - I tried this earlier but it did not work.